# selecting only newest row with specific value

Tags: mysql

Table:

```
person | borrow_date  | is_borrowed | SN | date        | id
1      | 2019-01-10...| 1           | 20 |2019-01-10...| 6
3      | 2019-01-09...| 3           | 10 |2019-01-09...| 5
1      | 2019-01-08...| 1           | 10 |2019-01-08...| 4
2      | 2019-01-08...| 1           | 10 |2019-01-08...| 3
1      | NULL         | 2           | 20 |2019-01-07...| 2
1      | NULL         | 2           | 10 |2019-01-07...| 1
```

My wanted output is to select newest rows where "is_borrowed" equals 1 and grouped by SN, so that when the query is executed with person=2 or person=3 then it would retrieve empty set. Whereas for person=1 it would give back two rows.
Wanted output (where person=1):

```
person | borrow_date  | is_borrowed | SN | date         |id
1      | 2019-01-10...| 1           | 20 | 2019-01-10...|6
1      | 2019-01-08...| 1           | 10 | 2019-01-08...|4
```

Wanted output (where person=2):

```
EMPTY SET
```

Wanted output (where person=3):

```
EMPTY SET
```

This is my current query and it sadly doesn't work.

```
SELECT a.SN, a.is_borrowed,a.max(date) as date, a.person
FROM table a
INNER JOIN (SELECT SN, MAX(date) as date, osoba from table where person like 
"2"  group by SN) as b
ON a.SN=b.SN and a.date=b.date
WHERE a.person like "2" and a.is_borrowed=1
```

Comment: Why should it return an empty set for person 2?

Comment: Because I want to retrieve just the newest owner (if is_borrowed = 1 then that person has the device) so person 2 hasn't the device anymore as there is a newer record for that device (which is recognized by SN) with different number in person field

Comment: I was thinking `SELECT * FROM t WHERE is_borrowed = 1 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t AS x WHERE sn = t.sn AND is_borrowed = 1 AND date > t.date)` but it returns three rows because 3 and 4 have same date.

Comment: I'm going to try as I didn't write further dates (hours etc). Tho you didn't include the person field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understood you from the question and the comment you made under it, here's one way to do it without specifying the person:

```
select * 
from TableName as p 
inner join (select max(borrow_date) as borrow_date,
                   SN 
            FROM TableName
            where is_borrowed = 1 
            group by SN) as p2
on p.borrow_date = p2.borrow_date and p.SN = p2.SN
```

This should give you the result you're looking for. Here's a [demo](https://paiza.io/projects/ZsuJ6xTOq5bYENnMXLeTnQ?language=mysql).

Note that I had to change the `borrowed_date` values in the table since yours contain hours and minutes while I didn't add those.

You can always specify it for each person by adding a `where` clause after the join.

```
select p.person, 
       p.borrow_date, 
       p.is_borrowed, 
       p.SN, 
       p.date, 
       p.id 
from TableName as p 
inner join (select max(borrow_date) as borrow_date,
                   SN 
            FROM TableName
            where is_borrowed = 1 
            group by SN) as p2
on p.borrow_date = p2.borrow_date and p.SN = p2.SN
where p.person = '1'
```

Output:

```
person | borrow_date  | is_borrowed | SN |  date        | id
1      |  2019-01-10  |     1       | 20 |  2019-01-10  | 6   
1      |  2019-01-08  |     1       | 10 |  2019-01-08  | 4
```

While `where p.person = '2'` and `where p.person = '3'` will return empty sets.

Comment: But person needs to be specified as each user has to know what devices he borrowed

Comment: SN is the device number, right? If that so, then this query will give you each person with the SN he has currently. You can always specify after the `on` clause in the query a `where p.person = '1'`